# Unable to send <ACK> over serial port to communicate with lab machine?

Tags: python, python-3.x, serial-port, port, pyserial

When i am testing using hercules to send data,
i am just typing the string "< ACK >" and sending it to serial port, i am receiving the data

But, from my python code, when i am able to receive the "" from machine but when i am sending "" nothing happens please help? Short snippet for my code?

```
//CONNECTION SETTINGS
addr = "COM1"
baud = 9600
ser = serial.Serial(
  port = addr,\
  baudrate = baud,\
  parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,\
  stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,\
  timeout=0)

// OPENING PORT
ser.portstr

// SENDING DATA ---- this is how i am sending data
serialcmd='<ACK>'
ser.write(serialcmd.encode())
```

but it is not working, please help, how to send ''...
i feel there is something wrong with it

serialcmd='< ACK >'
ser.write(serialcmd.encode())

Comment: Please send b'<ACK>' directly instead of substituting and encoding. [Docs » Short introduction](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/shortintro.html) Although 0x06 is ACK in the ASCII code table, this 1 byte may be transmitted. [ASCII Code](https://www.ascii-code.com/) Please check the specifications of the communication target device.

Comment: thanks! i used b'\x06' and it worked! can you tell me how to generate my string to something like '\x06'???

Comment: Please see the data types described here. [Binary Sequence Types — bytes, bytearray, memoryview](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#binary-sequence-types-bytes-bytearray-memoryview)